# STM32: Running many peripherals at the same time

Tags: stm32, emc

I need to do [EMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_compatibility) testing for a board controlled by an STM32F2. Ideally, I want to activate, full-speed, every peripheral on the board.

That is, I want to be reading/writing as fast as possible to the memories (SD, Flash, RAM) and putting/receiving as much as possible through the communication channels (Ethernet, USART). All of this, *at the same time*.

At the moment I have individual drivers for each peripheral, but the drivers are "blocking", meaning that when one driver operates, all the others are idle.

How can I have all my peripherals churn full-speed at the same time?

*Note*: I don't really care *what* the peripherals do, just that they be very active.

Comment: You could cheat a little by quickly multiplexing between each device. Perhaps something where you read something into memory, then push it to SD, then back to RAM, then discard. In the idle times whilst SD is writing (assuming you're using interrupts) you can just read random pages from RAM to increase the effect.

Comment: If your drivers are blocking, how will you ever have all of the peripherals operating at the same time in real life?  There's no need to do EMC testing for something that can't happen!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to exercise *every* peripheral, only those you use in your product. STM32 has clock gating and nearly all optional peripherals are disabled at startup. You only need to be concerned about peripherals that you enable in your production firmware.

As far as simultaneous operation is concerned, if you actually need that (it seems a different mode of operation from your production code which you say is blocking, so EMI may be different, too), you have 3 options: interrupts, DMA and preemptive RTOS tasks. Each of these is a topic in itself, but many examples exist, e.g. most examples that come with the standard peripheral library are interrupt-driven. Note that small implementation details may again result in very different performance (and therefore bus and peripheral activity). Making "all peripherals churn full-speed at the same time" is a very challenging task if you actually mean that literally.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to activate everything at once. **You do need to do some near field emission sniffing** before you even think of going to an FCC/CE test facility.

Get a scope probe and make a ground loop to the tip and connected the 10MΩ probe to a 50Ω spectrum analyzer.  Find out all your hot  spots and then see what's leaking thru your shields and cables. **I/O cables will be your biggest radiators** as well Clock distribution chips on board. 120MHz is your core clock so watch for harmonics and sub harmonics.

Having done this a dozen times or more, I can help with solutions like CM chokes, shielding and low ESR caps. Don't forget ingress testing.